# What are the 22 short films in "22 Short Films About Springfield"?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-simpsons

Commonly referred to as the "Pulp Fiction" episode of The Simpsons, season 7's episode titled "22 Short Films About Springfield" is a series of short stories about a minute long. However, by my count there are only 18 individual segments and I feel I've been liberal in my separation (e.g., the Reverend Lovejoy scene could be argued to have been the opening of Lisa's Hair part 2).

So am I missing 4 segments? Or did they miscount? Maybe the title is meant as a reference that I don't get?

1. Bart and Milhouse on the bridge
2. Apu goes to a party
3. Lisa gets gum in her hair part 1
4. Burns and Smithers on a tandem bike
5. Dr Nick saves the day
6. Snake robs Moe's
7. Super Intendent Chalmers and Skinner have lunch (steamed hams)
8. Maggie gets trapped in a newspaper box
9. Springfield PD talk about McDonald's in Shelbyville
10. The Spanish Bee goes home from work
11. Military surplus store part 1
12. Reverend Lovejoy's dog poops in Flanders' lawn
13. Lisa's hair part 2 (half the town in the kitchen)
14. Cletus the Slackjawed Yokel
15. Comic Book Guy won't let Milhouse use restroom
16. Military surplus store part 2
17. Lisa's hair part 3 (the haircut)
18. Nelson vs tall man in small car

Comment: I always wonder this too every single time I watch this and it never adds up. Why didn't I ever ask that question? ;-)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The name of the episode is a reference to the film [Thirty Two Short Films About Glenn Gould](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108328/), which like the episode is an anthology of vignettes.

On the DVD commentary they explain that they chose it because they liked the name.

> You'll notice that there are not 22 short films. We insisted on the name from the beginning, though we never bothered to count how many are actually done.
>
> I know that George Meyer was extremely irritated by that but we did it anyway. We kept cutting them out.
>
> There's one cut out at the last minute, which you'll see in the outtakes.

In addition, showrunner Josh Weinstein [recently tweeted](https://twitter.com/Joshstrangehill/status/1250204981589770240) an additional cut scene featuring Hans Moleman.

They don’t state it explicitly, but the reason the writers liked “22” specifically is most likely referencing the fact that an episode of *The Simpsons* (or most half hour American network TV shows) has 22 minutes of “show”.

That said, there are a few that you have not counted: at the end Bart and Milhouse have an epilogue, and Professor Frink attempts to tell his story before being cut off by the credits.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/22_Short_Films_About_Springfield) lists 21 total, though it is not explained why the first Lisa segment counts for two. Given its position in the episode, I believe there may be a commercial break between when she is on the kerb and when she is inside with Marge.

Comment: Interesting. I did consider that they might have been counting the final bridge scene and the Frink credit roll as two more, but I didn't consider they would split the first Lisa scene. There's also a short little transition sequence between the Snake/Quimby scene and Reverend Lovejoy where a donut falls into the sewer and travels in a radioactive river to a different street grate which I considered might possibly have counted as a short film although its only about 4 seconds long. So with the 21 from wikipedia plus the donut scene that would make 22...